# wp_get_archives with coun

Tags: wordpress

Can I add the count number to wp_get_archives list?

```
Archives
- Auguest 2010 (12)
- July 2010 (9)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using this property:

```
show_post_count=true
```